# Why aren't my ItemsControl ZIndex bindings working?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got some lines using a datatemplate and I need to change their ZIndex often so I've bound a property of the class that holds the line data to the ContentPresenter's Panel.ZIndex property but it isn't working. I've checked to make sure the bound ZIndex property is getting notified when it changes and it is. Am I missing something here? I don't get any errors or binding failures either.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="MapPageItemsControl" 
                Width="700" Height="500"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MapPageBaseClassList}" 
                MouseMove="MapPageItemsControl_MouseMove"
                VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="Transparent" Width="700" Height="500"
                    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Path=ZIndex}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ItemsControl.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CanvasLine}" >
            <Path x:Name="canvasLine" 
                    StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}" 
                    Visibility="{Binding Layer.IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Data="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LinePathConverter}}" StrokeDashCap="Round" 
                    StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeMiterLimit="14" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round">
                <Path.Stroke>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CanvasObjectColorConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="canvasLine" Path="DataContext.Layer.Color"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="canvasLine" Path="DataContext.BaseColor"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="canvasLine" Path="DataContext.ColorByLayer"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="canvasLine" Path="DataContext.IsSnapped"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="canvasLine" Path="DataContext.IsHighlighted"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Path.Stroke>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ItemsControl.Resources>

</ItemsControl>
```

Here is my the base class where the property ZIndex is found:

```
[Serializable]
    public class CanvasBaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int zIndex = 0;

        public int ZIndex
        {
            get { return zIndex; }
            set
            {
                zIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ZIndex));
            }
        }

        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Here's my constructor for the page:

```
public MapPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
```

Comment: From what you are showing here it is unclear why the ZIndex won't work. Please show the relevant parts of your view model.

Comment: Apologies. Added.

Comment: Still nothing obviously wrong. As a note, there is however a lot of strange stuff in your XAML. `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing` has no effect on a Canvas. `StrokeMiterLimit` has no effect when `StrokeLineJoin` is `Round`. `<Binding ElementName="canvasLine" Path="DataContext.Something"/>` could just be `<Binding Path="Something"/>`.

Comment: @Clemens, nope, ElementName is set so Path="DataContext.Something" is needed. Without the DataContext part, the binding would bind to properties of the Path itself.

Answer (score -1):

Some questions:

- Why would you want to use ZIndex on lines? At least, i don't see a Fill on the Path so why is the Zindex important? Edit: ah i see, the strokes have different colors
- I assume that MapPageBaseClassList contains models that derive from CanvasBaseClass? That is, CanvasLine?
- Why would you bind the Path's data to its DataContext (=CanvasLine) and use a Converter to retrieve the data; can you not just expose the data on CanvasLine?
- Why do you set VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"? This is only used when some element is inside a VirtualizingPanel. Which implicates some ScrollViewer.

Also a remark, instead of putting the DataTemplate under the ItemsControl.Resources, you can simply assign it to ItemsControl.ItemTemplate.

Furthermore, setting a Name on an element (canvasLine) inside an ItemTemplate is trickey, since then there are multiple elements with the same name in the same namescope. Sp i wonder if that MultiBinding works well, instead of using Binding ElementName="canvasLine" i think you can also use Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}. Not sure if Self is the Path or the MultiBinding.